# Objective-C: Как сделать бесконечное количество параметров функции, не требующее nil-терминации и NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Создаю приложение для OS X, статистика показала, что актуальны версии от 10.6 до 10.12, поэтому Swift не подошел.

Пишу на Objective-C, по возможности создаю свои utility.

Потом это еще понадобится для iOS, у которой, возможно, с новыми версиями лучше и поэтому подойдет и Swift, но и он не столь лаконичен как бы хотелось.

Больше всего мешает отсутствие в Obj-C операторов конкатенации строк.
Для этого тоже надо написать util.

На досуге надо бы сделать так.

```
NSString *str = $(@"Привет ", @"jQuery", str0);
```

Хотя это уже перебор, лучше так.

```
NSString *str = [$ str s:@"Привет ", @"jQuery", str0];
```

Данная функция также будет иметь перегрузку, принимающую int и т.д., чтобы их преобразовывать к NSString, но это другая история.

А сейчас речь о том, как реализовать эту функцию, чтобы обойтись без такого.

```
NSString *str = [$ str s:@"Привет ", @"jQuery", str0, nil];
```

А особенно без такого (когда параметр всего один).

```
NSString *str = [$ str i:5, nil];
```

То есть без лишнего nil.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вас так смущает необходимость добавлять `nil` в конец аргументов функции с переменным количеством параметров, то можете попробовать сделать несколько обёрток для данной функции под конкретное количество параметров (я примерно такое же видел в библиотеках для C++). То есть если у Вас есть функция вида

```
-(void)funcWithVarArgs:(id)firstString, ... {

    id eachObject;
    va_list argumentList;
    if (firstString) {

        NSLog(@"%@", firstString);
        va_start(argumentList, firstString);
        while (eachObject = va_arg(argumentList, id))
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", eachObject);
        }
        va_end(argumentList);
    }
}
```

То Вы можете сделать обёртку для вызова с одним аргументом

```
-(void)funcWithOneArg:(id)firstString {

    [self funcWithVarArgs:firstString, nil];
}
```

или с двумя аргументами

```
-(void)funcWithTwoArgs:(id)firstString secondString:(id)secondString {

    [self funcWithVarArgs:firstString, secondString, nil];
}
```

Именно эти две функции Вы можете в дальнейшем вызывать. Более элегантное решение Вы получите с языком Swift, однако я понимаю, что Ваш проект должен поддерживать и более ранние версии операционных систем, поэтому довольствуйтесь тем что есть в Objective-C.

Ещё как вариант можете передавать в качестве первого аргумента строку с форматом выводимых данных, затем на её основе проверять закончились ли аргументы функции. Возможно Вас это устроит, но тогда у Вас не получится адекватной проверки количества аргументов функции, что возможно приведёт к падениям Ваших программ или совсем жестокому коду.

Comment: Ну, это плохое решение для данного случая, а как функция NSLog() реализована? В ней не нужно "nil"! Можно было бы дизассемблировать фреймворк Foundation или где реализовано, но нет желания, там непролазное болото поверх Си, это направление реверс-инжиниринга очень плохо развито, думал на форуме ответят.

Comment: Насчет версий ОС, а другие проекты не должны? Можно примеры таких проектов, где у всех пользователей хотя бы 10.9? А то смотрю на статистику своего, и на список target'ов в Xamarin, да и в самой Xcode последней версии, и формируется такое впечатление, будто Swift лучше вообще отложить до лучших времен, лет на пять.

Comment: @Rou1997 NSLog работает со строкой, в которой описан формат выводимых данных, она ориентируется прежде всего на то что Вы там написали (в таком случае действительно nil в конце не нужен). Тем более Вам Xcode выдаст предупреждение в случае если количество/тип аргументов не соответствуют тому что указано в её первом аргументе (а всё потому что эта функция помечена как NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION). Насчёт версий ОС можно долго спорить, но лично я уже версии без Swift давно не поддерживаю, ибо не надо заказчикам. И ещё раз повторюсь - да, решение корявое, но что-то получше Вы вряд ли найдёте в Objective-C.

Comment: Пока что в голову пришло только очень нехорошее решение - применить @try-@catch, и когда попытка чтения очередного аргумента приведет к исключению - то прекратить чтение.

Comment: @Rou1997 То есть по-вашему это будет более элегантным решением?

Comment: @Rou1997 Я немного отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56637/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-rou1997).